# Recovering a file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I securely deleted a file in Linux by:

1) First encrypting it with AES (cipher block chaining)

2) Then using srm which does 38 passes (as explained in man srm)

Any pointers on how to recover it?

Comment: You don't own an electron microscope by any chance ...

Answer (score 2):

You can't, or at least should not be able to, if `srm` did its job right. If you want the file back, you will have to restore it from backup or from another location where it still exists which you most likely don't have.